# Pygame wait for key down

Tags: python-2.7, pygame

I have problem waiting pygame event.I need to quit pygame.display when any key pressed.I tried to use this:`pygame.event.wait()`,but it quitted after starting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you need:

```
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        pygame.quit()
        quit()
```

So what this does is it basically goes through pygame.event.get and checks if any of the keys have been pressed, and if so it quits the program. If you only want to quit pygame.display then leave out the `quit()` at the end.